# AWS spot instance pricing bid value

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have tried bidding on a c5.xlarge instance with a max unit per hour of $0.03 given the pricing on the webpage says: $0.0663 per Hour, so that would be just under half.

And yet, it says on the dashboard:

```
Status

price-too-low: Your Spot request price of 0.03 is lower than the 
minimum required Spot request fulfillment price of 0.097.
```

How can the price advertised be 0.0663 and when I request it for 0.03, it tells me that the minimum is 0.097?

Comment: Which region are you using?

Comment: @kirrmann eu-central-1

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137848

> A bid status of 'price-too-low' also shows you the price of the market
>   at the time your bid was evaluated. Your bid was not fulfilled as it
>   was below the Spot market price. For your bid to be successfully
>   fulfilled you will have to bid above the market price. If you bid
>   lower, your bid would only be fulfilled if the market moves to below
>   your bid price at a later point.

So it seems that 0.097 was the current market price and 0.0663 is the default/minimum for c5.xlarge

Comment: What do you mean by default/minimum? The market price graph said 0.0663 was the current market price.

Answer (score 0):

Spot pricing will fluctuate based on available capacity in the region and is per instance type and per availability zone. The price on https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/ is an indication of the region price. To get closer to the actual price you are proposing to bid against you could consider using the API to look at the availability zones.

There have been changes recently to spot pricing that aims to even out pricing variation: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-amazon-ec2-spot-pricing/

On one occasion in ap-south-east-2 we had one availability zone for m4.large which tripled in price, while the other zones remained at historically normal prices. As part of troubleshooting I wrote the following simple python script that may help you to understand current prices in your region:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()

print "Local Time:", str(datetime.now())
print "UTC Time  :", str(datetime.utcnow())

endTime = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
startTime = endTime-timedelta(hours=1)

def outputSpotPricing(az):
    response = ec2.describe_spot_price_history(
        AvailabilityZone=az,
        EndTime=endTime,
        InstanceTypes=[
            'm4.large',
            'm4.xlarge',
        ],
        ProductDescriptions=[
            'Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC)',
        ],
        StartTime=startTime,
        MaxResults=3
    )

    print "\n---------AvailabilityZone", az
    for price in response['SpotPriceHistory']:
        print "Price:", price['SpotPrice']
        print "Time :", str( price['Timestamp'].astimezone(to_zone))

outputSpotPricing('ap-southeast-2a')
outputSpotPricing('ap-southeast-2b')
outputSpotPricing('ap-southeast-2c')
print ''
```